# How to best leverage Capacitor introduction besides just performance improvement?

Tags: google-bigquery

Below quote is from [Google BigQuery cuts historical data storage cost in half and accelerates many queries by 10x](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/03/google-bigquery-cuts-historical-data-storage-cost-in-half-and-accelerates-many-queries-by-10x)

> Among the many improvements, Capacitor is able to operate directly on
>   compressed data, rather than the traditional method of decompressing
>   the data first. This vastly increases efficiency of data processing

Will this change pricing to be based on compressed data vs. uncompressed?

From what I remember, uncompressing data stored in bigquery  - was the main reason for charging based on uncompressed size. If now this phase eliminated  - will price approach be changed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about product pricing, not programming.

Comment: it is not just about pricing - it is about understanding options programmer has to better leverage improved engine

Comment: @duffymo In BigData – cost aspect is important part of coding patterns / best practices. Being able to understand and leverage cost model lead to better code / applications. I would appreciate if you can reconsider your down-voting!

Comment: Edit the question and I will.  Any change will unlock it.

Comment: thank you for consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no change in pricing, or any other user visible change (except that some queries will suddenly start working much faster). Capacitor is being rolled out already, and some lucky projects already got it. Rollout will take some time, but eventually all projects will be on it.

Comment: Thank you Mosha. Is there way to know when or if already particular project is alreay lucky to be rolled in?

Comment: Contact me offline at select lower(concat(firstname, left(lastname, 1), '@google.com')) from (select "Mosha" firstname, "Pasumansky" lastname)

Comment: Deploying SQL-aware spam-bot now... ;-)